# Given logits, how to calculate logits corresponding to the average of probabilities in a numerically stable way?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, probability, ensemble-learning

Suppose I have n logits in a tensor `l` of shape `[n]`. They are in (-∞, +∞) and correspond to probabilities in (0, 1) via the formula `p = torch.sigmoid(l)`. I want to calculate one logit `l_averaged` - a tensor of empty shape - such that `torch.sigmoid(l_averaged)` approximately equals `torch.mean(p)`. I want to do this in a numerically stable way. Ideally, this means that I don't want to actually invoke the `torch.sigmoid` function. How do I do this?

If you wonder why I am doing this, then the answer is that I've got an ensemble of neural networks and I want to average their predictions.

Comment: had you consider using ReLU instead of sigmoid?

Comment: @IdanRotbart I don't use sigmoid as an activation function. I use it as a function that transforms the outputs of my neural network into probabilities.

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. From what I know, there isn't a way to avoid the sigmoid in order to compute the average over outputs. The one thing that comes to mind is that I recall hearing about something called the annealed approximation in which (waving hands here) the average and sigmoid are exchanged. I seem to recall that's a fair approximation at high temperatures, i.e., you don't look too closely at it. I don't know if that's at all useful; I just mention it as a possible search term. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: @RobertDodier I don't think the question is offtopic here, but anyway, I've created the question on stats as well: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/581766/how-to-calculate-sigma-1-frac1n-sum-i-1n-sigmax-i-in-a-numer

Comment: Well, the audience here is not going to be able to respond knowledgeably about the question -- you are more likely to find a suitable audience elsewhere.

Comment: @CrabMan In this framework they calculate the average of the probabilities
link: https://github.com/TorchEnsemble-Community/Ensemble-Pytorch/blob/908761dcd4a0e4a9b3c14d0ed3a2e6e87f8bc3b2/torchensemble/fusion.py#L43
I think this is how it should be done.